# squid proxy server at windows server 2012

Tags: windows, squid

I want to allow some users to use social media on my server on specific time.i have configured that using squid proxy server.but now i want some of our marketing employees to allow social websites permanently.any body have guidence or solution kindly help me.

Comment: How are you handling authentication or differentiation between your marketing team and the other employees?

Answer (score -1):

May be you should use Web filter app as SquidGuard together with Squid. Please see [this](https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/SquidGuard_package) link which helps to configure and know how to Web filter integrating with Squid

Comment: Your answer isn't what he's asking and linking to off site content is never a good idea.  You should fully explain your answer